# $watch isn't called after one directive is initiated in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying call up to do focus of a element in directive of modal.
After the directive is called the focus-me directive is called only first time.
I tried adding the focus-me element in dialog directive as shown in the Plunker.
Below are things which I am trying in the directive.

1. Show the Modal dialog box [working]
2. After the dialog box is shown i am trying to focus a specfic element in the dialog box [For which i added watch element in focus-me directive]
3. The Focus is happening only for the first time. 
   [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lCyeIV4S23ODDlbgvLtS)

    Please help with,how to trigger the watch element on the directive for the above Plunker. Thanks a lot.

Below is the directive code for the focus and dialog which i am currently using.`

```
app.directive('focusMe', function($timeout, $parse) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.focusMe);
      scope.$watch(model, function(value) {
        console.log('value=',value);
        if(value === true) { 
          $timeout(function() {
            element[0].select(); 
            element[0].focus(); 
          });
        }
      });
      element.bind('blur', function() {
        console.log('blur')
        scope.$apply(model.assign(scope, false));
      })
    }
  };
}).directive('modalDialog', function(){
   return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      show: '=',
    focusDesign:'=focusDesign'
    },
    replace: true, 
    transclude: true, 
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


      scope.dialogStyle = {};
      if (attrs.width)
        scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
      if (attrs.height)
        scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
      if (attrs.focusDesigniso)
        scope.focusDesigniso=attrs.focusDesigniso;
      scope.hideModal = function(focusDesign) {
        scope.show = false;  
        focusDesigniso=false;
          //$scope.focusDesign=false;
      };
     scope.hideModalC = function() {
         alert("I m in hide");
         scope.show = false;
      };
    },
    template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'><div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal(focusDesign)' ng-model='focusDesign'></div><div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'><div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal(focusDesign)' ng-model='focusDesign'>X</div><div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div></div></div>"
  };
});
```

Comment: That is because the directive is still living on the background it doesnt get re-initiated. You are actually not re-initiating the directives, what you doing is re-opening the modal. So if you want to do anything do it with the relevance to the modal toggle event. You could for example broadcast event accross rootScope and catching it in focusMe directory and re-run the focus

Comment: Thanks Tom. Can you brief me on the re-run on the rootScope. I am really confused on the directive scope here.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast

Answer (score 1):

I got solution for the problem in the directive.
The $scope.apply i was applying it model instead i should i used for the element in focus. 

The updated the directive of focus i have copied below with working Plunker

```
   app.directive('focusMe', function($timeout, $parse) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.focusMe);
      scope.$watch(model, function(value) {
        console.log('value=',value);
        if(value === true) { 
          $timeout(function() {
            element[0].select(); 
            element[0].focus(); 
          });
        }
      });
      element.bind('blur', function() {

        scope.$apply(function()
                     {
          attrs.focusMe=!attrs.focusMe;
        })
         })

    }
  };
});
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vM1zFX7iCd3rl4GKrhWI?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Man , it really helps :)